# Investigating minidump without having all binaries from process

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, minidump, postmortem-debugging

Our company provides set of dll's to customers, and from time to time there is a need to fix some completely rare unknown exception, or crash, which we can't reproduce on our machine. Now I'm thinking if I should use simple stacktraces, or dump more detailed information with MiniDumpWriteDump?

I afraid there might be one possible problem with minidumps: I'm not sure if it provides any useful information when we don't have all executables/dll's that were loaded in process at a time of dump creation. Because obviously customers call API of our DLL from their own dll/exe, and they won't give us executables/debug symbols/sources for their own binaries. I know that under Linux in similar situtation with core dumps we won't be able to obtain any useful information from core dump (https://sourceware.org/ml/archer/2008-q4/msg00119.html).

So my minimal goal with minidumps is to reliably achieve stacktrace from our DLL's, without having executables/dll's that call our dll. And it would be great to achieve state of local and global variables.

So the question is: Will minidumps work for me in case when I don't have executable/dll that called my dll?

Comment: I'm very skeptical that "debugging" of minidumps can provide enough info without the resp. binary (not to mention the resp. pdb files). What I know: my collaborator responsible for such issues ensures that build binaries (incl. pdb-s for releases) are archived in our build system. (With git checkout of the resp. tags, we would even be able to rebuild it - with a bit more effort.) What we usually request from the customer is the build number (the build date and time) to easily find the resp. release in archive. This is what I would recommend (at least for your future releases).

Comment: How do you even now it's a bug in your library and not in the calling executable?

Comment: They are still useful in determining the stack trace and the state of the application at the point of the crash. You may not be able to identify the exact offender but you can determine are you at fault or is the client not respecting the api/contract. Besides you can always provide the dump back to the customer and tell them it's an error in their code

Comment: As long as you build (and keep) the corresponding .pdb for the release .dll you distribute, then the crash dump should show you the call stack within your code only if the crash occurred in your code. If the .dll and .pdb don't match then you're likely to get garbage.

Comment: @Scheff, I obviously have pdb files and sources for my dll's, and I'm interested in obtaining debug info only for my dll's. I just wanted to know if it's possible to obtain info/debug such dump without having customer's binaries that called my dll.

Comment: @SergeyA, Customer will ask me to check why their process crashes after they call our dll :). Besides that I'm planning to integrate crash dumping into SEH handler that I set for all our threads with _set_se_translator.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev, sure. But how do you know it is not the customer who violated contract, passed a bad pointer or simply corrupted the memory? For example, more than once I found my application crashing inside `std::string` destructor, but I do not imagine it's a bug in STL implementation. May be you should do it other way around? Send customers your .pdb and ask them to walk the crash, give you the stack and may be state of interesting variables?

Comment: @SergeyA, you are right, but I'm thinking about situation when customer already checked input on their side, with our PDB's (but without sources), and needs to give us as much information as possible for analyzing.

Comment: Yeah, that's a tricky scenario. I believe, if I were in your situation, I would try to provide pdbs to customer (as suggested by SergeyA) and, may be, doing a common debug session (via TeamViewer) to involve all "responsibles". (But I know that sometimes customers are very sensible to let you look into their stuff...)